# Android Loading more videos takes long time

Tags: android, augmented-reality

I am currently experimenting Vuforia VideoPlayback Sample application. To do that i have to load videos from asset folder.  When i tried to load more videos it takes long time to load them from asset folder so could you please suggest me any solution to tackle this problem.

Comment: You can load them into the memory from the beginning.

Comment: I can't get what you are saying